# Pandas 10digit number extraction

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with financial data and want to extract any 10digit number from each cell of a certain column. Cells can look like this: 'RECLASS 1239875309823 APPLE 0123456789 INV'. The 10digit number can be located in the start of the string, just before the end or anywhere in between. Is there any way I can write a function that does that that does not take forever to run?(Dataframe has more than 100k rows)

Comment: You can use a regular expression `\d{10}`.

Comment: Can you please show your wanted output of your example? Right now it is not clear if you want to match the frist number with 10 digits or more or if you want to match the number with exactly 10 digits.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I want only the number with EXACTLY 10digits

Comment: Has this number always a whitespace on both sides?

Comment: The 10digit number can have any kind of value next to its sides, spaces, letters, special characters or end of string

Comment: So rigth now no answer is correct?

Comment: your answer seems to work, I'll accept it @mosc9575

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I got your example correct. Below you can see, how you extract a number with 10 digits in pandas using a regular expression.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':['RECLASS 1239875309823 APPLE 0123456789 INV']})
df['num'] = df['value'].str.extract(r'(\b\d{10}\b)')
df
>>>
                                        value         num
0  RECLASS 1239875309823 APPLE 0123456789 INV  0123456789
```

Comment: Please distinguish the case of 10 digits or longer or exactly 10 digits.

Comment: Good, seen you adjusted it.  The question has 2 numbers thus we need to know what exactly OP wants by the exact wording.  I think OP has set a good sample to see if we can extract it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract those of exactly 10 digits but not anything 10 digits or longer, use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':['RECLASS 1239875309823 APPLE 0123456789 INV']})
df['extracted_10_digit'] = df['value'].str.extract(r'(\b\d{10}\b)')

                                        value extracted_10_digit
0  RECLASS 1239875309823 APPLE 0123456789 INV         0123456789
```

Comment: Sorry. How is this answer different to mine?

Comment: Yours extracted the first number which is longer than 10 digits.  Mine extracts the 2nd number of exactly 10 digits.

Comment: This is worth a comment, so I can correct it. The approche is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'cell_value':['RECLASS 1239875309823 APPLE 0123456789 INV']})
pat = r'\b[A-Z]+\b'
df['cell_output']=df['cell_value'].replace(pat,'',regex=True).astype(str).str[:11]
df
```

```
    cell_value                                  cell_output
0   RECLASS 1239875309823 APPLE 0123456789 INV  1239875309
```

Comment: what if data contains 10 digit twice??just like -  **RECLASS 1239875309823 APPLE 0123456789 INV 1231231232**